How reliably can I drive the northern route cross country (USA) in November?
I need to drive from New Hampshire to Portland, Oregon for Thanksgiving, and I have 5 days to do it. The most direct way to is take interstates 90, 80, and then 84. That's about 3,000 miles, so 600 per day.
I can handle the long driving days, time wise, but I don't have much sense about the weather at that time of year in the Midwest, Plains, Rockies, and through Idaho and Oregon.
Historical weather reports that I've been researching suggest that the temperatures should mostly be above freezing, and snow is not likely. But I don't have much slack in the schedule and definitely don't want to drive through any real weather.
Does anyone have experience doing this drive--or portions thereof--at this time of year and can say whether I am likely to have the weather I would need to accomplish it?

I would suggest that you have an emergency kit with your.  A warm jacket, blanket and some flares at a minimum.  Blizzards can make driving impossible and if you have to just pull over and wait it out you'll want to stay warm.  We had a couple inches of snow for Halloween two years ago and that was the Chicago area.

Frame challenge: Why do you have to drive?  Unless you either (a) have a car full of passengers or (b) need independent transportation when you arrive, you could probably find a flight that costs less than the fuel alone for your trip.  Would save you a lot of time, too.  So ask yourself, is driving through the scenery of the great American north your ideal way to spend the 4.5 days difference in time

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If you have 5 days to make the trip, don't plan for an ideal split of 600 miles each day.  Plan to make the trip in 4 days (750-800 per day) so that you have flexibility for when your plan inevitably runs up against the real world.
If you plan for an optimal split, and you only make 300 miles the first day due to conditions, you have four days to make that up.  But if you start the final day at the 2400 mile mark, you have no tolerance for problems.
Include a healthy amount of slack in your plan.

I read the last phrase as "include a healthy amount of snack in your plan". Still good advice.

If you assume an average driving speed of 50 miles per hour then 800 miles is a 16 hour driving day. OUCH

In many places traffic on interstate highways flows at about 70 MPH if driving conditions are good. Which is certainly not guaranteed, but I think it's realistic to expect you can go more than 50 MPH on average as long as bad weather isn't involved.

@DavidZ - again, west of the Mississippi traffic will flow closer to 80. It is easy to average 65 or better including stops.

That should be doable but weather is very difficult to predict, so your best shot is to keep an eye the weather forecast while you are going and adjust if needed.
It's certainly useful to look at the elevation profile of the possible routes. In this regard staying north on I-90 seems a safer option. It peaks at 6300 ft as compared to 8640 ft for I-80. You would have to make this call after you pass Chicago.
I-84 has a top elevation of about 4200 feet but steep grades and sees its fair share of winter accidents, but there is no real practical way to avoid it without a massive detour.
Again, there are no guarantees here. Chances are, you will be fine, but it's also possible that you run into bad weather or even road closings. You just have to monitor it and react to the current conditions.

Yes, to get across the continental divide, I-90 is much easier than I-80 which is easier than I-70...

+1 Having driven some of these routes before, I agree that elevation is the biggest compounding risk to otherwise drivable weather. Elevation also is significant in the performance of any vehicle that does not have a turbocharger.

Keep in mind that I-90 and I-80 are major arteries for cargo traveling to and from the ports in the Pacific northwest.  There aren't a lot of alternate routes that cut across the Rockies.  Any closures or slowdowns on one of these would cause an enormous logistical problem that would cost a tremendous amount of time and money to work around.  For that reason, the Powers That Be are very highly motivated to keep these roads clear and flowing at all times.  I have been on the I-90 corridor through Montana during extremely gnarly weather on multiple occasions and I've always been very impressed at the crews working around the clock to keep the roads clear and open.  If you stick to the major interstates, it's unlikely that you'll have any surprises (and if you do, there's nearly always a well-marked detour around it).
That being said, these roads have lots of large trucks driving on them.  This can be dangerous in some conditions because they can pass you and kick up loose snow, creating a solid wall of white where you can't see anything for several seconds.  Interstate traffic can average in the 10-15 mph range when there are lots of trucks during whiteout-prone conditions.  One bad stretch of road can mess up your whole trip if you try to make your schedule too tight or let your fuel level get too low.
Also, be aware of the wind gusts in the great plains. They can get seriously strong when a cold front is moving through.  Big trucks will block the wind for you but you're in for a nasty surprise once they pass you.  I've seen the sudden burst of wind knock unsuspecting cars completely off the road.  Make sure to leave plenty of space around you.

Upvoted just for mentioning the gusts. I did I80 once in a mid-sized RV, which yeah presents a lot of surface area to the wind, but also had some weight to it. I have no idea how much better or worse it would have been in a far lighter passenger vehicle, but I certainly wouldn't want to see worse.

IRRC, that stretch of the interstate had a lot of signs warning about what might happen if they have to close the road ahead too. Like permanent signs, as if this is an expected common issue there.

On the other hand, I drove through Vail Pass on I-70 in March, 2002 mere moments before they closed it because of inclement weather. They didn't even have to bring out DOT trucks or state police, they have (or at least did have) a system in place to close the road involving gates and red lights and a warning siren. My point is, major trucking routes or not, they do close roads when the conditions are bad enough. Stuff can still get cross-country on trains or on I-40.

@T.E.D. One of my in-laws reported seeing a big rig pulling an empty flatbed trailer somewhere in Nebraska. A wind gust got under the trailer, lifted it up, and moved it into the next lane (oncoming traffic).  Thankfully it missed any cars, although several had to swerve off the road to narrowly miss it.  I'm sure the locals are used to it but if you're not from around there, it can be a really nasty surprise.

I live not far off of I-80 in Iowa, and for the most part, unless there's a big winter storm, the roads should be clear and fine.  Even if there's been a storm in the last few days (which is unlikely prior to Thanksgiving at least east of the Rockies), the DOT (Department of Transportation) crews are well trained in ice/snow removal.
Though for any winter driving, make sure to have an emergency kit, and ideally don't run your fuel tank down to less than half.  Also, if you're running a pure EV, cold weather really knocks down the distance you can travel, especially if you're using heat to keep the inside of the car warm.
Probably also plan on staying on major interstate roads and not try and take shortcuts on random non-busy other roads due to the lack of services.

I-80 in Wyoming has some bad stretches during winter storms. But if the OP checks the weather ahead of time and can plan around them, it is definitely passable.

They are pretty good in places like Wyoming of closing the interstates and having places for people to park together. They don't want people stranded all along the highway in the middle of nowhere (and there is lots of middle of nowhere in Wyoming).

WSDOT reports on the weather for Snowqualmie pass starting on Nov 1 of each year. From this we can conclude that there is a chance of a pass closure any time from November to April. How likely you are to get stuck for multiple days is very hard to predict.
If you want to predict your transit time, you might really want to cross the plains and particularly mountains considerably further south.
There are requirements for traction tires or chains: https://wsdot.com/travel/real-time/mountainpasses/tiresandchains.

Not sure with what you mean by "further south". I-70 is probably the worst option  with a peak elevation of over 11,150 feet. Even I-40 goes up to almost 7300 fee but is arguably warmer. I-10 is the easiest of the bunch but that would be a massive detour.

When the movers moved us from Boston to Seattle in February, I believe that they ended up on I-40. I'm not an expert on closures on that pass.

Yikes, That's a 12+ hours detour

While this doesn't directly answer your question, I'll share some details of a trip that I did from Toronto to Vancouver towards the end of November in 2019. The geography and distances are pretty similar.
We had two drivers, myself and my father and were also pulling behind a small 5x8 trailer. The trip was mostly uneventful, it was especially easy to do 1200+ Kms on the days that we traversed across the prairies.
The mountain passes across the Rockies in the last stretch was another story however, we took the Crows Nest pass, which is the lowest of the 3 passes. It had snowed the night before and we had an early start, the snow clearing on BC highways is rather poor compared to the other provinces and there was a stretch of about 15 Kms where we ended up driving on the wrong side of the highway as the right lanes were covered in snow and we could only see the tracks towards the left. We only realized this when we saw an oncoming semi flash their lights towards us, that definitely gave me a scare.
My vehicle has all-weather tires and not the 3 peak snowflake winter rated tires, and there were stretches on the final day where we lost traction and the vehicle slipped across the road, we weren't speeding and were able to regain control and plough through.
Knowing what I know now, I wouldn't do this trip again; especially not in a rush. If I had to do the trip again, I would definitely have the right tires on my vehicle and also learn to use snow-chains, it's not obvious or easy to deploy those if you don't have prior experience. That said you're probably not going to need chains on the interstate system, except when climbing typically steep passes. And if there is a storm, then I'd probably hunker down and only head out later in the day by when the roads have been cleared and have had some traffic, starting at 5 am, I wouldn't recommend.

The plan is to drive only in clear weather. If there is any kind of storm, we wait it out. What I'm trying to figure out is the likelihood of such a storm on this route at that time of year.

The weather in the mountains is especially unpredictable, that said the interstate system is pretty well taken care of. So unless a major system develops, I think you'll have a scenic and uneventful drive.

@JoshuaFrank, I've been in Yellowstone National Park in July during a snowstorm. The Rockies do their own thing, year round.

The numbers say "fly" as others have already pointed out. I too prefer driving, however. Maybe it's the being-in-control factor. I made 20+ years of drives from Denver to Sacramento for winter holidays. It wasn't always the smart thing to do, but we got through safe in the end each time. Weather in the west can be sudden and dangerous.
The road east to west will be easier than the return trip (which you don't mention needing). Heading westward, any storms you hit will generally be moving against you, and so will pass relatively fast, even if you can't keep moving. However, coming back towards the east you can easily find yourself in a situation where you stay under the same storm for days since it can move at the same speed as you. Storms don't stop to gas-up, pee, eat or sleep.

Another option sort of halfway in between the two might be to take the Amtrak Empire Builder train from Chicago. It looks like it takes about 2 days, and I understand the views are spectacular.

Being in control is important to us, as is seeing all sorts of interesting things along the way. Money wise, I'm sure flying makes much more sense. For the trip back, we're thinking of heading way south on the west coast and then heading east, and thereby avoiding any snow storms (although we once barely stayed ahead of a bllizzard in Amarillo, TX, so perhaps that's not a totally reliable plan either).
